# How can I get the count of options in a select list in PHP

Tags: php, twig, html-select

I have options that are populated conditionally in Javascript. In php, I need to get the count of options a particular select box has, then do a function based on the count of options.

Another idea is to put the option values in an array?

I was trying to avoid Javascript or jQuery bc I have to pass this info to a twig file to display a div with instructions for the user if something doesn't appear in the list.

HTML

```
     <select id="cars" name="cars">
        <option val="honda">Honda</option>
        <option val="nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option val="toyota">Toyota</option>
     </select>
```

PHP

```
    foreach ($_GET['cars'] as $item)
    {
        var noOfCars = count($item);
        if ($noOfCars == 3){
            //do something
        }   
    }
```

Comment: This whole example doesn't make sense. For one thing you have 3 identical options which is meaningless, secondly a select only posts back the option which was actually selected (you can have a multiple select but yours isn't configured for that so only one value will be sent back), thirdly you didn't give the select a name so it won't be sent in a regular postback anyway, and fourthly why would PHP care about the number of options anyway? Surely it only needs to know which one the user selected. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you are posting the selection via a html form, php will only receive the selected option. You will not be able to run a foreach loop. If you are generating the dynamic select with JavaScript, it will be better to count it in JavaScript and post the value separately with a (hidden/text)  input field in the form.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry putting this together. I was trying to avoid Javascript or jQuery  bc I have to pass this info to a twig file to display a div with info for the user if something doesn't appear. Is there a way to put the option values in an array?

Comment: You have three options in the **one** form field (select) what's more, that `select` doesn't even contain a `name` attribute, therefore is **never sent**. Please get some basic knowledge about sending form data before asking. Tip for this case: Use JavaScript (probably jQuery) for counting the options in the select, then set the value of it into a hidden field in your form and sent it to the PHP script.

Comment: Please excuse my rush and see my edits.

Comment: I'd use jQuery still (as you probably already using it)for this and fill the hidden field after populating options, if you won't manage it yourself I can give you simple sample for that.

Comment: So you have two pages is that right? And if a select on the first page doesn't contain a certain option(s) then you want to do something different on the next page is that right? How do the options in the first select get chosen? By some earlier PHP code? If so then might make more sense to put that info in the session perhaps, or in a hidden field. Or is it all on the same page? The whole scenario is still a bit obscure

Comment: Anyway even if you were to put `<select id="cars" name="cars" multiple>`, then `$_GET['cars']` will only contain the _selected_ item(s), not all of them. Once you post back the form containing the select, PHP only sees the form data submitted, not the HTML which was used to generate it. Hence the suggestion to maybe put the original count of options into a hidden field to submit with the same form, or even into the Session if the options were originally generated by server-side code.

Comment: Indeed, ADyson's right, if these options were generated with PHP and weren't modified with JS on the client-side of course whole that thing with updating hidden fields wouldn't make any sense, but you should specify that so I assume that what I think that you think is correct  @user3038672  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're generating your select's option dynamically with JS, you should also count it with JS, then you need to put the number of options into hidden field, so it can be sent:

```php
<form action="script.php" method="post">
    <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="car_options_count" id="carOptionsCount" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="car_options" id="carOptions" value="0">
    <input type="submit" value="Send the form">
</form>

<script>
    // populate additional options
    let $cars = jQuery('#cars');
    $cars.append(new Option('Opel', 'opel'));
    $cars.append(new Option('Honda', 'honda'));

    // some time later... count options in your select and set the value in hidden form's field
    let $options = jQuery('#cars option');
    jQuery('#carOptionsCount').val($options.length);

    // You can even send these dynamic options the same way as a JSON stringified object
    let optArray = [];
    $options.each(function () {
        let $el = jQuery(this);
        optArray.push([$el.val(), $el.text()])

    })
    jQuery('#carOptions').val(JSON.stringify(optArray))
</script>
```

and read it in your PHP script from `$_POST` array:

```php
<?php

// validation of input data skipped, but should be done here
echo "You have {$_POST['car_options_count']} options available in your form, and selected exactly: '{$_POST['cars']}' option <br>";

$options = json_decode($_POST['car_options'], true);
var_dump($options);
```

Comment: Check my edit to see how to send all options as an array to PHP script, in such case you can skip counting in JS, as you can also count array elements after JSON decoding.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!